# how to show 2 strings on each wpf/MVVM combox row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

EDIT: This actually works with both scenarios but retracing the changes did not help me to find the real problem. So the template was not source of the problem.

i have a class for each row:

```
public class OptionItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string BitMap { get; set; }
}
```

now when my XAML is like below everything works (shows label):

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="OptionsComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OptionsItemsSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Label" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOptionItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

but when i try to (mis)use ItemTemplate, the combobox is empty (get-accessor for ItemsSource is called normally and has items):

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="OptionsComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OptionsItemsSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOptionItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BitMap}"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The rest of the things are below. I know I use our own classes that are not explained here, but I would like to emphasize that combobox works without template (only has 1 of the strings though) so these shouldn't be too interesting.

The property for selected item in ViewModel:

```
    private OptionItem _selectedOptionItem;
    public OptionItem SelectedOptionItem
    {
        get { return _selectedOptionItem; }
        set
        {
            // to raise property changed
            SetValue(ref _selectedOptionItem, value);
        }
    }
```

and itemssource in ViewModel:

```
    private ItemsSource<OptionItem> _optionsItemsSource;
    public ItemsSource<OptionItem> OptionsItemsSource
    {
        get { return _optionsItemsSource; }
        private set
        {
            // to raise property changed
            SetValue(ref _optionsItemsSource, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `WrapPanel` isn't displaying the items correctly? If you change the template to only contain a `TextBlock` that is bound to the `Label` property, does that work?

Comment: @Andy : thanks. I just finished a test that I chose to try only label -> worked, then I used StackPanel with both Textblocks Orientation=Horizontal -> also worked. Make an asnwer if u want and i can accpet it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the `WrapPanel` isn't working right when used in an `ItemTemplate`. Try using a horizontal `StackPanel` instead:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BitMap}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: it actually works now for me also with wrap so not wrap vs stack issue. i tried to backtrace changes to find out what change caused it to start to work, but i can't.

Comment: ok, i tried to get back to original situation but just can't reproduce. sorry to waste ur time. it has been something else. maybe i fixed something already just before trying with DisplayMemberPath. then immediately tried the different template again and thought that fixed it. sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

WrapPanel works fine for me:

```
    <ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=", " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

My `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection`, however:

```
    public ObservableCollection<StudentViewModel> StudentList
    {
        get { return _studentList; }
        private set { _studentList = value; }
    }
```

Comment: it actually works now for me also so not wrap vs stack issue. i tried to backtrace changes to find out what change caused it to start to work, but i can't.

Comment: ok, i tried to get back to original situation but just can't reproduce. sorry to waste ur time. it has been something else. maybe i fixed something already just before trying with DisplayMemberPath. then immediately tried the different template again and thought that fixed it. sorry to waste your time.